# Springboot not persist nested object

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

Recently I start learning java and spring boot, so I decided make a basic prototype service system. But I getting some problems on persist relashionship there contains oneToMany or manyToMany references.

I've create table "**service_order**", "**services**" and "**service_order_services**" (Pivot table that make the relashion between service_order and services). So my database entities look this:

---

**service_orders**.id > **service_order_services**.service_order_id

**service**.id > **service_order_services**.service_id

---

I already bring from get request this relashion from database (when manually inserted), but when I try to persist this information, neither row are created...

My request to create a service order look as this:

```
{
    "status": { "id" : 1 },
    "title": "Manutenção de compressor de ar",
    "address": "Rua São João do Rio preto",
    "dateSchedule": "2020-07-12T13:30:30+05:00",
    "contactName": "Pedro Rocha",
    "contactPhone": "11 6670-2132",
    "contactEmail": "pedro@fakenterprize.com",
    "details": "Manutenção preventiva no compressor de ar modelo RPX921 Série 4. Notas: Levar produtos para limpeza de peças.",
    "services": [{ "service_id": 1 }]
}
```

My action in SO controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> create(@Valid @RequestBody ServiceOrder serviceOrder) throws JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    this.repository.save(serviceOrder);

    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(serviceOrder);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(json);
}
```

SO Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "service_orders")
public class ServiceOrder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "serviceOrder" )
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<ServiceOrderService> services;

    public Set<ServiceOrderService> getServices() {
        return services;
    }

    public void setServices(Set<ServiceOrderService> services) {
        this.services = services;
    }

    //... (Other properties)
}
```

Service Order Service Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "service_order_services")
public class ServiceOrderService {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_order_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private ServiceOrder serviceOrder;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Service service;

    public ServiceOrder getServiceOrder() {
        return serviceOrder;
    }

    public void setServiceOrder(ServiceOrder serviceOrder) {
        this.serviceOrder = serviceOrder;
    }

    public Service getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my code? It's necessary to manually iterate and save all rows of service order services in my controller before persist this SO or JPA make this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

your code looks a bit confusing so im gonna assume what you want to do;

1. Addressing only the fact that jpa is not saving nested object. To solve this issue you have to use cascade in your annotation `@OneToMany(mappedBy="serviceOrder",cascade= CascadeType.ALL)`
2. I dont see the use of your pivot table if you only have @OneToOne relationships. So im assuming you want to do Many To Many between Service And ServiceOrder class; In this case make Relationships in ServiceOrderService Entity @ManyToOne and that will be your manually created ManyToMany table; But if you do then you will have to pass ServiceOrderService object to your ServiceOrder.
3. Shortcut to do what you want would be to do follwing:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "service_orders")
public class ServiceOrder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
    name = "service_order_services", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "service_order_id), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "service_id"))
    private List<Service> services;

    public List<Service> getServices() {
        return services;
    }

    public void setServices(List<Service> services) {
        this.services = services;
    }

    //... (Other properties)
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "services")
public class Service {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "services")
    private List<ServiceOrder> serviceOrders;

    public List<ServiceOrder> getServiceOrders() {
        return serviceOrders;
    }

    public void setServicesOrders(List<ServiceOrder> serviceOrders) {
        this.serviceOrders = serviceOrders;
    }

    //... (Other properties)
}
```

Relevant articles:
[ManyToMany](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types)
[Cascading](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types)